# How to pass a class with Toplevel widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image]

I have a readymade game([2048](https://github.com/kiteco/python-youtube-code/blob/master/build-2048-in-python/2048.py)), where the game starts without a welcome window, so, I have just made a welcome window with a bunch of buttons like New Game and AI mode, now when I click the New Game button, I expect to get a new window where the game can be played. However, the game displays at the bottom of the main window, and another window that is supposed to display the actual game displays nothing.

```
# mainwindow.py file:
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import game_2048
 
root = Tk()
 
root.iconbitmap('unnamed.ico')
root.title('2048')
 
 
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("welcome.png"))
 
my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=780, height=550)
my_canvas.grid()
 
my_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=bg, anchor=NW)
 
button1 = Button(root, text="New Game", fg="black", bg="#ddf0d0", padx=3,
                 pady=3, font=('Helvetica', '12', 'bold'), activebackground="#94d3c3", command=lambda: game_2048.mains(root)
                 )
button2 = Button(root, text="AI Mode", fg="black", bg="#ddf0d0",
                 padx=3, pady=3, font=('Helveica', '12', 'bold'), activebackground="#94d3c3")
 
button1_window = my_canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor=NW, window=button1)
button2_window = my_canvas.create_window(120, 10, anchor=NW, window=button2)

root.mainloop()
```

And I have tried to modify the game_2048 file i.e. [2048](https://github.com/kiteco/python-youtube-code/blob/master/build-2048-in-python/2048.py) game like this:

```
def mains(root):
    Top = Toplevel(root)
    l1 = Button(Top, command=lambda:Game())
    l1.pack()
 
 
class Game(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.master.title('2048')
 
        self.main_grid = tkinter.Frame(
            self, bg=c.GRID_COLOR, bd=3, width=400, height=400)
        self.main_grid.grid(pady=(80, 0))
        self.make_GUI()
        self.start_game()
 
        self.master.bind("<Left>", self.left)
        self.master.bind("<Right>", self.right)
        self.master.bind("<Up>", self.up)
        self.master.bind("<Down>", self.down)
 
        self.mainloop()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mains()
```

I am pretty sure that I have made some mistakes in the mains() function as a result of which I am not getting the desired output. So my question is what should I do to rectify these mistakes?

Comment: why do You call mainloop when inheriting from Frame? also You are not passing the argument `root` to the `mains` function. btw `Toplevel` doesn't need `mainloop`

Comment: Hi, are you implying that ```self.mainloop()``` should be removed? I just passed root to the ```mains``` function, also, I did not understand the third part of your comment. Thanks!!

Comment: all that is needed to show `Toplevel` is just calling it like this `Toplevel(parent)` (and passing the parent/master argument), there is no need for `mainloop` for `Toplevel`. `self.mainloop()` is certainly not necessary and I would say it should get removed. mainloop is usually called as `Tk` method, for example `root.mainloop()` also don't do it in this specific class.

Comment: Hey, I just removed the ```self.mainloop```, I have passed root as the argument, and modified to ```l1 = Button(Top, command=lambda: Game())``` from ```l1 = Button(Top, command=Game())```, yet, the game still appears below the mainwindow and not in the other window that I made using Toplevel. What do you think I should do next? Thanks for your kind help!!

Comment: Does the duplicate marked answer your question

Comment: @martineau The OP did ask somewhat same question before and it was marked as same duplicate, I don't think the duplicate is the only problem, could you reopen it.

Comment: yes, I rectified that part of the problem, and it looks like @martineau  glanced at my question, saw that part where I had missed the lambda, and just shut the question down, it's so frustrating, I have been trying to work this project out for so many days and at the end, it gets shut down without being fully analyzed

Comment: or should I ask the question again and hope it doesn't get shut this time?

Comment: No do not ask a new question, it can get you flagged. Be patient

Comment: What you can try right now is `def __init__(self,parent):` and then `tkinter.Frame.__init__(self,parent)` and then `l1 = Button(Top, command=lambda:Game(Top))`

Comment: by parent you mean 'root', right?

Comment: Define it as `parent`, no It means `Top`.

Comment: When I run the code, I get a new window that asks me for New Game or AI mode, without any changes

Comment: Hey, @CoolCloud, here is the code: https://github.com/SUSHANT-REGMI/2048, do check this out, if you could help, it would be great!!!

Comment: Tell me what is wrong and what you expect it to become

Comment: Okay, I have a readymade game(2048), where the game starts without a welcome window, so, I have just made a welcome window with a bunch of buttons like New Game and AI mode, now when I click the New Game button, I expect to get a new window where the game can be played. However, the game displays at the bottom of the main window, and another window that is supposed to display the actual game displays nothing.

Comment: So, my speculation is that the reason I am not getting the desired output is because the way I modified my mains function inside of the game_2048 is not correct. However, I don't know the correct way. Btw I just added you on facebook

Comment: Okay this game right, when you press the button that is inside `mains` where do you want to show the game, in the same window? Or a separate one.

Comment: I want to show it on the separate window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes I made to your code:

- Removed `import mainwindow` from `game_2048.py`, as it will lead to circular import calling the functions twice.
- You created a class inheriting from a `Frame`, this frame is just like any other tkinter widget, requires to be placed in the window using geometric manager, like `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()`, you did not do that
- I also destroyed the `root` window before creating another new `root` window. Also note that instead of using `Toplevel`, I used `Tk`. This is done, so that closing the game window will close the app. But if using `Toplevel`, you will have to close the menu window too.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import random
import colors as c

def mains(root):
    root.destroy()
    root = Tk()
    
    def init(root):
        l1.destroy()
        game = Game(root)
        game.pack()

    l1 = Button(root, text='Start Game',command=lambda: init(root))
    l1.pack()

class Game(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        .......
```

But if you were to ask me, I would not go for such structure, but this will work here too. Understand this, work on it, implement your own structure that does not call more than one `Tk()`.